# The long run average amount of time the deviation of Brownian motion spends above its expected value

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $B_t$ be a standard one dimensional Brownian motion. Is it true that

$$\lim_{s \to \infty} \frac{\int_{[0, s]} \mathbf 1_{ \{|B_t| \geq \sqrt{2t/\pi} \} } \ dt}{s}$$

exists almost surely?

Comment: The integral of your random variable is $2\Phi(-\sqrt (2/\pi))$. On the other hand, by the Law of the Iterated Logarithm, there are times when $B_t>\sqrt((2-\epsilon)t\log\logt)$. At such a time, it will likely remain above its expectation for a period of order $t\log\log t$, so the $\limsup$ of your random variables is 1 a.s.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean the expected value of the random variable?

Comment: I think   $\lim \frac 1 s \int_{[0, s]} \mathbf 1_{ \{|B_{e^{2t}}| \geq \sqrt{2e^{2t}/\pi} \} } \ ds$ exists because 
$  B_{e^{2t}}/ e^t$ is an ornstein uhlenbeck process

Comment: Sorry. I mean the random averages appearing inside the limit have expectation strictly between 0 and 1; but there are long periods when $|B_t|$ is above its average, so the limsup of the random averages is almost surely 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limsup is 1 (as noted by Anthony Quas) and the liminf is zero. The first of these follows immediately from Strassen's functional LIL. The liminf can be deduced from the distribution of the running maximum  of Brownian motion.

[1] https://sites.stat.washington.edu/jaw/COURSES/520s/523/HO.523.20/523-Spr2020-L4.pdf